# Create an array in windows workflow foundation

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

Is it possible to create a new array in windows workflow?  More specifically, in the designer.

I've created a variable of `System.Int32[]`, but when I use it I get a `NullReferenceException`.
I've tried `New Int32(5)`, and various permutations of `Dim` - nothing I have tried has worked.

I was able to create the array and pass it as an in/out parameter - this works, however the workflow will need to determine the actual size of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create and instantiate an array, you have to set a default value to your variable with `New Int32(FOO SIZE){}` or use an Assign activity to instantiate it with the correct size in runtime

You can also use List(Of T) or any other .NET collection structure to achieve dynamic size.

Note that the value must be the right part of a set expression. So, you can google how to do it in VB.NET and you will be fine.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks!  In an assign activity, I was able to use "New Int32(5) {}" - the {} is what I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that if you are creating the array in the designer, as you stated, it is either a workflow variable or a workflow argument.  The "WF" way to do this would be to use the "Default Value" column under the "Variables" and/or "Arguments" tab.

If it is an argument then the Default Value column only works if the Direction is "In".  If your argument is a property, or an Out, or In/Out direction then you would have to use the method mentioned by Davi.

If you are creating it under the "Variables" tag then using the Default value column would be the more built-in approach. The syntax in the default column would be the same syntax mentioned by Davi: `New Int32(FOO SIZE) {}`